# bash set -eo pipefail not immediately exiting

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eo pipefail

sha256sum \
    Dockerfile-ci \
    frontend/pnpm-lock.yaml \
| sha256sum
```

If `frontend/pnpm-lock.yaml` does not exist, and the script above is run

```
sha256sum: frontend/pnpm-lock.yaml: No such file or directory
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
```

It correctly logs that the file doesn't exist, but it continues piping that into the next `sha256sum`. Shouldn't `set -eo pipefail` immediately exit the script on the first `sha256sum` command and not pipe into the second `sha256sum`?

Answer (score 6):

`pipefail` doesn't cause the pipeline to abort early if a command fails. The pipeline still runs to completion, until all the commands have exited. That's true with or without `pipefail`.

What `pipefail` does do is ensure the return status is a failure if any of the commands fail. Without `pipefail` the pipeline fails only if the *final* command fails.

From the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines) (emphasis added):

> The exit status of a pipeline is the exit status of the last command in the pipeline, unless the `pipefail` option is enabled (see [The Set Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin)). If `pipefail` is enabled, the pipeline’s return status is the value of the last (rightmost) command to exit with a non-zero status, or zero if all commands exit successfully. If the reserved word `!` precedes the pipeline, the exit status is the logical negation of the exit status as described above. **The shell waits for all commands in the pipeline to terminate before returning a value.**

Answer (score -2):

try to use below flag then it work. I have validated it.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e -o pipefail

# to reset use
# set +e +o pipefail
```